# Can I place the .NET framework on a machine without needing admin privileges?

Tags: .net, installation, privileges

The application that I'm building requires the .NET framework.  Unfortunately our end users will not have admin privileges.  I know it isn't possible to install .NET without admin privileges, but is it possible to build a pre-packaged version of it into our system so the user doesn't need admin privileges?  If it is possible, how would I go about doing it?  One approach I have heard is to place the neccessary .dll files in the same folder as the executable, but that didn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool like Xenocode's PostBuild:

http://www.xenocode.com/Products/Postbuild-for-NET/

Answer (score 0):

No, but assuming that the individual who installs your app must have admin proviliges to install a new app on the machine, You can have the msi installer for your app also install the framework for you...

But if you're hoping to have your app installed by someone without admin priviliges, then I believe you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Either go with something like Xenocode (BobbyShaftoes's answer) or get .NET installed on the destination machines before you distribute your application. If you're on an Active Directory this can be done pretty easily through group policy.

- .NET 1.1: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323886
- .NET 3.5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc160717.aspx